# Logic require, structure confuse on query

Tags: php, mysql

My query is doing compare to the database data, if database content is equal or bigger than search criteria($musage) then select the data into result.

*-1 is a value mean "Unlimited"

the problem is when database data is -1, "in fact it smaller than every positive integer", but in my database it is bigger than every number. The select query is executed to get database's content into result, how can make a situation to control when database content is equal -1?

here is my code:

```
$device = $_POST['device'];
$provider1 = $_POST['provider1'];
$plantype = $_POST['plantype'];
$dusage = $_POST['dusage'];
$cusage = $_POST['cusage'];
$musage = $_POST['musage'];
//default query
$MSGQuery = " plan.`MSG` >= $musage ";
//when search criteria is unlimited
if( $musage == 'Unlimited' ){
    $MSGQuery = " plan.`MSG` = -1 ";
}//when search criteria is 0
else if ( $musage == 0 ){
    $MSGQuery = " plan.`MSG` >= -1 ";
}
else {
    $MSGQuery = " plan.`MSG` >= $musage ";
}
echo $planquery="
                    SELECT plan.*, details.* FROM plan
                    LEFT JOIN details ON plan.`Name` = details.`Name` 
                    WHERE plan.`Phone` = '$device'
                    AND plan.`SIMTYPE` = '$plantype'
                    AND plan.`DATA` >= $dusage
                    AND plan.`CALL` >= $cusage 
                    AND $MSGQuery ";
$planresult=mysql_query($planquery) 
    or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
while ( $prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($planresult) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition:

```
...
AND (plan.`DATA` >= $dusage OR plan.`DATA` = -1)
...
```

Do not forget parentheses since AND has greater priority than OR.